# Mock Authentication on dev-profile

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, security

I was trying out spring boot 3.1.x and was wondering if there is a simple solution to mock a user for a oauth2ResourceServer for the dev profile. Using quarkus this is very easy to achieve but I struggle with SpringBoot.

Basically the setup is a resource server behind an oidc proxy that is not running on the dev machine. So some kind of fakeuser which would be configured (roles/claims) via application.properties is needed to act like a JWT being present of the request. So that every consumer of the principal recieves an authenticated principal with the specified roles.

How can I implement a solution like this?

Answer (score 0):

My current solution looks like this:

I add an OncePerRequestFilter faking auth by setting `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication` to an implementation of `AbstractAuthenticationToken`.

```
override fun doFilterInternal(request: HttpServletRequest,
                                  response: HttpServletResponse,
                                  chain: FilterChain) {

  val principal = JWTClaimsSet.Builder()
                 .claim("sub", sub)
                 .claim("email", email)
                 .build();

  val authentication = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, null, roles.map { SimpleGrantedAuthority(it) })
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = authentication

  chain.doFilter(request, response)
}
```

Roles, sub, email is injected via config to mock the user as required. I did not bother using the correct AuthToken Implementation since I don't need that fit.

This code should (like I mentioned in the question) only run on local dev since it is obviously a security problem

Answer (score 0):

I detailed how to use mocked OAuth2 authentications in unit and integration (`@SpringBootTest`) tests in this [Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-oauth-testing-access-control).

You have to options:

- use what is in `spring-security-test` for OAuth2: `MockMvc` requests post-processors (`SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors` like `jwt()`) or `WebTestClient` mutators (`SecurityMockServerConfigurers` like `mockJwt()`)
- use the [test annotations I wrote](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons#unit-tests) (and publish on Maven central)

As a disclaimer, I wrote all that (what is in `spring-security-test` for OAuth2 and I'm the owner of the repo for spring-addons). I have personal preference for annotations because it works when testing not only `@Controller` with `MockMvc` or `WebTestClient`, but also any other kind of `@Component` (like `@Service` or `@Repository`) using method security.

Sample usage for the very polyvalent `@WithMockAuthentication`:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = { SecurityConfig.class, MessageService.class })
class MessageServiceTests {

    @Autowired
    private SecuredService securedService;
    
    @Test
    @WithMockAuthentication("BAD_BOY")
    void givenUserIsNotGrantedWithNice_whenCallNice_thenThrows() {
        assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> securedService.nice());
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockAuthentication(name = "brice", authorities = "NICE")
    void givenUserIsNice_whenCallNice_thenReturnsGreeting() {
        assertThat(securedService.nice()).isEqualTo("Dear brice, glad to see you!");
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @AuthenticationSource(
        @WithMockAuthentication(name = "brice", authorities = "NICE"),
        @WithMockAuthentication(name = "ch4mp", authorities = { "VERY_NICE", "AUTHOR" }))
    void givenUserIsAuthenticated_whenCallHello_thenReturnsGreeting(@ParameterizedAuthentication Authentication auth) {
        assertThat(securedService.hello()).isEqualTo("Hello %s.".formatted(auth.getName()));
    }
}
```

Sample usage for `@WithJwt` which uses the authentication converter bean in the configuration (what implements `Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken>`, like `JwtAuthenticationConverter` does)`:

```java
@Import(AuthenticationFactoriesTestConf.class) // when using spring-addons-oauth2-test but not spring-addons-starter-oidc
// @AddonsWebmvcComponentTest // when using spring-addons-starter-oidc along with spring-addons-starter-oidc-test (already imports AuthenticationFactoriesTestConf for you)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { SecurityConfig.class, MessageService.class })
class MessageServiceTests {

    @Autowired
    private SecuredService securedService;

    @Autowired
    WithJwt.AuthenticationFactory authFactory;
    
    @Test
    @WithJwt("igor.json")
    void givenUserIsIgor_whenCallNice_thenThrows() {
        assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> securedService.nice());
    }

    @Test
    @WithJwt("brice.json")
    void givenUserIsBrice_whenCallNice_thenReturnsGreeting() {
        assertThat(securedService.nice()).isEqualTo("Dear brice, glad to see you!");
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("identities")
    void givenUserIsAuthenticated_whenCallHello_thenReturnsGreeting(@ParameterizedAuthentication Authentication auth) {
        assertThat(securedService.hello()).isEqualTo("Hello %s.".formatted(auth.getName()));
    }

    Stream<AbstractAuthenticationToken> identities() {
        return authFactory.authenticationsFrom("brice.json", "igor.json");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure for tests. But this is not about testing. It is about running the application without the oidc provider present.

Comment: Why not using a local instance, then? `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` is most probably not the type of authentication you have at runtime and switching user profiles is gonna be a hell with your solution.

Comment: I am using a reverse proxy in production and I want to develop without having to startup/reproduce the whole containersetup locally. Only solution would be to have a proxy running locally and I dont want to install stuff like that locally for projects. Running docker would make reloading/devtools a hell to use I guess. Maybe there are better solutions...

Comment: I don't know exactly what your "OIDC proxy" is about, but did you ever have a look at how to configure `spring-cloud-gateway`  with `oauth2Login` and the `TokenRelay` filter? This is easy to run locally outside of a container. Also, it shouldn't be complicated to run everything but the resource server you are debugging in docker (lift a all dev stack, kill the container for the resource server you want to debug and start this resource server again from your IDE).